# Apache charset declaration

Tags: apache, encoding, utf-8

I just learned that AddDefaultCharset only applies to text/html and text/plain. So, i ran to add a AddCharset to my conf for most commonly affected files, like .css and .js ?
Is there a way to do a AddCharset by mime type rather than by extension, to do for example, something like AddCharsetByMimeType text/* application/* ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this by MimeType. There's only a way to this by extension.
If you want further informations you can take a look at [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addcharset) and at the full [list of runtime directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/quickreference.html) of Apache